# How to deal with PyCharm's "Expected type X, got Y instead"

Tags: python, numpy, pycharm

When using PyCharm, Pycharm's code style inspection gives me the warning `Expected type 'Union[ndarray, Iterable]', got 'float' instead` in the editor if I write `np.array(0.0)`. When I write `np.array([0.0])` I get no warning.

When coding

```
from scipy.special import expit
expit(0.0)
```

I get `Expected type 'ndarray', got 'float' instead`, while

```
expit(np.array([0.0]))
```

solves that.

What I think Pycharm's code style inspection wants to tell me is there's a possibility of a type error, but I am not sure how I should react to that in the sense of good programming. Is PyCharm right to scold me and should I use the long versions or should I keep my short versions for readability and speed of coding?

If I should not change my code to the long versions - can I get rid of the Pycharm's code style inspection warning, or is that a bad idea, because they may be correct in other cases, and I am not able to tune the warnings that specifically?

Comment: the function `expit` needs an `array(list)` , so when you pass the float `0.0` you get the error.

Comment: @Stack: I don't get an error. Only the warning from PyCharm. If you actually run `expit(0.0)` you get neither an error, nor a warning, just the result.

Comment: I think the question whether to modify the code or to ignore/disable the warning depends mostly on taste and personal preference.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

PyCharm determines from the type-hints of the source code that the arguments you pass are incorrect.

---

#### How to disable

Your question simplifies to one of figuring out how to disable this type checking. However, please be warned,

> Switching off the inspection completely is not a good solution. Most
> of the time PyCharm gets it right and this provides useful feedback.
> If it's getting it wrong, it's best to raise a ticket with them to see
> if it can be fixed.

You can do that like this:

1. Go to `Settings/Preferences`
2. On the sidebar, click `Inspections` (under the Editor category)
3. Expand the `Python` tab
4. Scroll down to `Type Checker` and uncheck it

PyCharm should now stop issuing warnings about incorrect function arguments.

Comment: Doesn't work. Tested on PyCharm 2019.1.2 (Community Edition).

Comment: In case this is still useful for someone: The tag to uncheck is `Type checker` instead of `Incorrect Call Arguments`.

Comment: Switching off the inspection completely is not a good solution. Most of the time PyCharm gets it right and this provides useful feedback. If it's getting it wrong, it's best to raise a ticket with them to see if it can be fixed.

Comment: @jon_two I was just answering their "can I get rid of the Pycharm's code style inspection warning" but I agree with your disclaimer and I added it to the answer. Thanks

Comment: Type Checker is no more but the bug is still there :(

Comment: In PyCharm 2022 its now called "Incorrect Type"

Answer (score 30):

If you want to ignore it for that specific line,

then you can put

```
# noinspection PyTypeChecker
```

above the line of code that is being marked.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer, the one below disables the warning completely, many times this is a valid / important warning, and you should only disable it on the line that you know it's reporting a false positive.

Answer (score 6):

Look at the [specifications of the expit function](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.14.0/reference/generated/scipy.special.expit.html). Nothing there says it's permissible to provide a scalar argument - it calls for a `numpy.ndarray`. PyCharm is smart enough to tell you that any iterable (and hence a list) is acceptable, but this message isn't a warning - it's telling you your code as written does not meet the function's specifications. As @JonClements points out in a comment, `numpy`'s scalar broadcasting feature will allow this code to run, but PyCharm isn't smart enough to deduce this.

NOTE: the answer from @cs95 explains how to disable the type checking, and it may be more appropriate as the accepted answer.

Comment: Funny, it doesn't throw an error when run. My guess is script implicitly converts it.

Comment: `expit(0)` returns the results without any warning or error though

Comment: @COLDSPEED: it may not throw an error, but that doesn't mean it's good code. Getting the results you want? Fine: ignore the warnings, but you are asking for trouble since there's no guarantee from the documentation this behaviour won't be excluded in future versions ...

Comment: @Make42 `expit` is a [ufunc](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/ufuncs.html) which does broadcasting as appropriate - although PyCharm isn't to know that scalars *may* be valid (whether it's actually correct/desirable for `expit` itself - I've no idea), so it can only warn based on the type hinting...

Answer (score 2):

As @brunodd said on a comment before, the correct tag to uncheck is `Type checker`.

- Go to `Settings/Preferences` (`Ctrl + Alt + S`)
- On the sidebar `Inspections`
- `Python` tab
- Uncheck `Type Checker` and hit `Apply`

This is really annoying, PyCharm fails to identify some types even though its right.

Comment: Type Checker is not more, but the bug is still there