# Warning: Expected type [Class Name], got 'Dict[str, int]' instead

Tags: python, pycharm

I'm building a class with methods that take dictionaries as inputs but Pycharm displays a warning.

'''
Expected type 'TestClass', got 'Dict[str, int]' instead less... (⌘F1) 
Inspection info: This inspection detects type errors in function call expressions. Due to dynamic dispatch and duck typing, this is possible in a limited but useful number of cases. Types of function parameters can be specified in docstrings or in Python 3 function annotations
'''

```
class TestClass:
    def __getitem__(self, index):
        return self[index]

    def get_keys(self):
        return list(self.keys())


dict_input = {'a':123, 'b':456}
TestClass.get_keys(dict_input)
```

So I get the warning here:

TestClass.get_keys(dict_input)

What does this warning mean and what's the approach to fix it?

Comment: Your code doesn't make much sense. `get_keys` is an instance method, you're supposed to call it on an instance of the class. But there is nowhere in your code that accepts a dict, so it's my clear where the keys are supposed to be coming from.

Comment: `get_key()` is a *method* - it would normally be called on an *instance* of `TestClass`, NOT `Testclass` itself.  It would take no parameters other than the implicit `self` passed to all methods, so I have no idea what that dict you're passing is supposed to do.

Answer (score 3):

A method such as the one you wrote is called an "instance method".

`self`, the receiver, should be an instance of `TestClass` (otherwise, many things could work wrong, such as `super`).

You could define `get_keys` as a static method, or use a simple function (without putting it in a class).

```
class TestClass:
    @staticmethod
    def get_keys(s):
        return list(s.keys())
```

You may want to read the [Python documentation about classes](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html) for more details.

Answer (score 0):

To specifically answer your question about the Pycharm warning, the warning that you're currently encountering is a [known problem](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/360002610899-Wrong-type-warning-when-working-with-dictionary) caused by Pycharm checking for types in the code, as PyCharm is confused because it expects a TestClass object but gets a dictionary object instead.

One way to deal with this is to disable that particular warning type, as paraphrased from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45670823/how-to-deal-with-pycharms-expected-type-x-got-y-instead?rq=1)

1. Go to Settings/Preferences
2. In the sidebar, click Inspections
3. Expand the Python tab
4. Scroll down to `Incorrect Call Arguments` and uncheck it
5. If that does not work, you can uncheck `Type Checker` instead.

---

Another more elegant method, although I'm unsure if it will resolve this PyCharm warning, is to add a decorator to your function, to let PyCharm know that your return type is a dict. The tutorial is [here](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/using-docstrings-to-specify-types.html), but your docstring will probably include this:

```
"""
:rtype: Dict [str,int]
"""
```

---

As an aside, you should probably use a `@staticmethod` decorator on your get_keys function, as mentioned by Jean, since it's taking in an object and returning its keys (and we don't want that object to access our TestClass data in the process).