# Trying to use enum as index works but gives warning in pycharm

Tags: python, enums, pycharm

I have this enum class:

```
class MtuType(IntEnum):
        GENERATED = 0
        CONSUMED = 1
        NET = 2
        PEAK_GENERATED = 3
        PEAK_CONSUMED = 4
        OFF_PEAK_GENERATED = 5
        OFF_PEAK_CONSUMED = 6
        PEAK_NET = 7
        OFF_PEAK_NET = 8
```

And later on, I am trying to use it like this:

```
.
.
.
        powers = [None] * 9
        if generated is not None:
            powers[History.MtuType.GENERATED] = generated * sample_interval
        if consumed is not None:
            powers[History.MtuType.CONSUMED] = consumed * sample_interval
        if net is not None:
            powers[History.MtuType.NET] = net * sample_interval
        if peak_consumed > 0:
            powers[History.MtuType.PEAK_CONSUMED] = peak_consumed * sample_interval
        if peak_generated > 0:
            powers[History.MtuType.PEAK_GENERATED] = peak_generated * sample_interval
        if off_peak_consumed > 0:
            powers[History.MtuType.OFF_PEAK_CONSUMED] = off_peak_consumed * sample_interval
        if off_peak_generated > 0:
            powers[History.MtuType.OFF_PEAK_GENERATED] = off_peak_generated * sample_interval
```

It works fine, but PyCharm is complaining about these lines (only):

```
            powers[History.MtuType.PEAK_CONSUMED] = peak_consumed * sample_interval
            powers[History.MtuType.PEAK_GENERATED] = peak_generated * sample_interval
            powers[History.MtuType.OFF_PEAK_CONSUMED] = off_peak_consumed * sample_interval
            powers[History.MtuType.OFF_PEAK_GENERATED] = off_peak_generated * sample_interval
```

with the following warning:

```
Unexpected type(s): (MtuType, float) Possible type(s): (int, None) (slice, Iterable[None])
```

I have tried to add .value:

```
            powers[History.MtuType.PEAK_CONSUMED.value] = peak_consumed * sample_interval
```

but I get the same error.  I have even tried casting to an int:

```
            powers[int(History.MtuType.PEAK_CONSUMED.value)] = peak_consumed * sample_interval
```

Any suggestions would be most welcome!

Comment: Perhaps [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45670823/208880) will help.

Comment: But it complains even when I cast it to an integer! And it doesn't complain about exactly the same implementation earlier

Comment: It's interesting to note that I didn't have any issues until I added the last six enums (peak & off-peak).